# Laravel transformer vs resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-resource

I am little bit confused about the difference between Laravel eloquent resource and transformers. When i should use resource and when i should use transformers. Did some research on it from [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) and [medium article](https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/how-to-start-using-transformers-in-laravel-4ff0158b325f) but its look like same purpose.

May be i have wrong concept about that. Any knowledge share from anyone will be appreciate.

Comment: it looks like `Transformer` is a third-party package,in the other hand, `Resources` is official

Comment: can you share with us some hints? what are you actually getting confuse?.

Comment: please visit those links i mentioned

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Laravel Eloquent API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) was released on Laravel 5.5.

Before this feature exists officially, there was a package from spatie called [`spatie/laravel-fractal`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) that's a wrap for [`league/fractal`](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/).

Both packages archives the same objective with different approach.

I prefer using the Eloquent API Resource since it's embedded on Laravel, so I reduce one (direct) dependency.

**Note:** The medium article uses the `Fractal` package, but this article is very superficial, you can find more detailed instructions on [`spatie/laravel-fractal`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal), it you decide to use it.

Comment: awesome. thanks for your answer. i was looking for that.

Answer (score -6):

Found this on a google search below your post:

You build out each "transformer" (which would be the equivalent of a "resource"), with the ability to include or not include whichever relationships you want solely based off the of request URL.

Comment: That's not the OP question, he asked the difference between using Laravel API Resource and Fractal Transformers.